# Signed array multiplier in Verilog

Tags: verilog, signed

I am trying to implement 8x8 signed multiplication. I have already implemented the unsigned array multiplier using full adders and half adders. For this, I am following a book named "Computer Arithmetic Algorithms" chapter 6 by Israel Koren. I know there are other algorithms but I want to implement in the following way and looking for help to understand the circuit (5x5 signed array multiplier).

[image]

In the above figure, the cell I consists of three positive inputs and thus implies an ordinary FA. On the other hand, the cells marked with II are with a single negative input and two positive inputs. The sum of type II can vary from -1 to 2. I'is having all negative inputs and II' is having two negative inputs and one positive input.

The arithmetic operation of a type II cell is described by the following equation, x+y-z=2c-s. Whereas, a normal FA's equation is x+y+z=2c+s.

The given values of the s = (x+y-z) mod 2 and c = [(x+y-z)+s]/2.

As per the book I & I' and II & II' are identical in terms of gate implementations.

So my questions are:

1. Why carry has a weight of 2 in x+y-z=2c-s or x+y+z=2c+s?
2. What does input -z signify for a FA? 2's complement of z? The 2's
   complement of z remains the same in 1 bit. What will be the case for two negative inputs?
3. How should the Boolean expressions look for s and c?
4. Any tips for pipelining an array multiplier?

As I will be implementing it in Verilog, an explanation from that perspective will be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question belongs on and is a duplicate of https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/483676/signed-array-multiplication

Comment: @dave_59 True. I posted it there as well. It is kind of urgent and I wanted to reach for help as much as possible.

Comment: This question is about hardware design and stackoverflow is a forum for coding. You need to understand the algorithms before you begin to describe it in Verilog code.

Comment: @dave_59 Thanks for the gentle reminder. My questions are meant for understanding the algorithm and since this platform can help with both perspectives I did not hesitate. I will keep that in mind for the future.